# ConnectionString in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, connection-string

I'm trying to do a method that return a dataSet, but the connection string doesn´t work.

I have tried this:

```
    public DataSet list()
    {
        // First Create a New Connection
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
        // Now Pass a Connection String To the Connection


        sqlConnection1.ConnectionString = "Data Source=mysite.com.br;User ID=admin_devr;Password=123456;Initial Catalog="rave_dbteste" providerName="System.Data.OleDb";
        // Now the Select statement you want to run
        string select = "select * from table";
        // Create an Adapter
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(select, sqlConnection1);
        // Create a New DataSet
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        // Fill The DataSet With the Contents of the Stock Table
        da.Fill(ds, "cdestacionamento");
        // Now Return ds which is a DataSet
        return (ds);
    }
```

what's wrong?

Comment: What error it gives? Also , I think you are missing closing " (quotation mark). And always put your connection string in your web.config or app.config.

Comment: A good link to follow : http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012

Comment: @bittech I have followed but doesn´t work...return error in connection string line

Comment: Whats the actual error? Does error appears when you build the application or when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not open the connection after the line of connection string  write following

```
sqlConnection1.Open();
```

and always put a check like this

```
 if (sqlConnection1.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    sqlConnection1.Open();
```

Comment: or post your error here , after reading the error experts can help you

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database requested in login 'rave_dbteste providerName=System.Data.OleDb'. Login fails.
Login failed for user 'admin_devr'.

Comment: Try changing your provider: providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" or re Check your login Credentials.

Comment: If you have sql server try to login using these credentials in you connection string , the sql server you are trying to connect is not responding either user doesn't exist

Comment: now, i'm getting the following error: SELECT permission denied on object 'table', database 'rave_dbteste', owner 'admin_devr'.